# Directed graph linear algorithm

Tags: dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would like to know the best way to calculate the length of the shortest path between vertex s and every other vertex of the graph in linear time using dynamic programming.

The graph is weighted DAG.

Answer (score 2):

What you can hope for is an algorithm linear in the number of edges and vertices, i.e. `O(|E| + |V|)`, which also works correctly in presence of negative weights.

This is done by first computing a topological order and then 'exploring' the graph in the order given by this topological order.

Some notation: let's call `d'(s,v)` the shortest distance from `s` to `v` and `d(u,v)` the length/weight of the arc from `u` to `v` (if it exists).

Then, for a node v that is currently being visited, the shortest path from `s` to `v` is the minimum of `d'(s,u)+d(u,v)` for each in-neighbour `u` of `v`.
In principle, this is very similar to Dijkstra's algorithm except that we already know in which order to traverse the vertices.

The topological sorting ensures that all in-neighbours of `v` have already been visited and will not be updated again. So, whenever a node has been visited, the distance it is assigned is the correct shortest path from `s` to `v`. Therefore, you end up with a shortest s-v-path for each `v`.

A full description and implementation can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-for-directed-acyclic-graphs/), which links to [these lecture notes](http://www.utdallas.edu/~sizheng/CS4349.d/l-notes.d/L17.pdf). I'm not sure where the algorithmic idea for this DAG algorithm was originally published in the literature.

This algorithm works for DAGs, even in the presence of negative weights/distances.

While a typical implementation of this algorithm will most likely not be done using dynamic programming explicitly, it can still be interpreted as such since the problem of finding a shortest path to a node `v` is computed using the shortest paths to the in-neighbours of `v`.
For further discussion on if/how this type of algorithm counts as dynamic programming, let me refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140623/is-dijkstras-algorithm-dynamic-programming).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible what you're looking for is Bellman-Ford algorithm, which is O(|V||E|) in terms of time complexity (not really linear).

Not sure if some witty dynamic-programming approach could improve on that though.

Answer (score 0):

As hauron said, Bellman-Ford will give you what you're looking for in time O(|V||E|). This works even if your graph contains negative weighted edges, and Bellman-Ford uses dynamic programming at its core.

However, I must add that if your weights are non-negative, you can do Dijkstra from your vertex s in time O(|E| log |E|).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `d[s] = 0`.

For every vertex, calculate:

```
d[v] = min {d[u] + w(u,v) | (u,v) is an edge}
```

`d[v] = ∞` if `v` has no incoming edges.

(The algorithm always halts since the graph is acyclic.)