# How to design linear dynamic programming algorithm for shortest path?

Tags: dynamic-programming, shortest-path

Given a weighed directed acyclic graph (G) and a vertex S of G. I want to design a linear time dynamic programming algorithm to find the length of the shortest path between S and every other vertex of G.

Comment: What makes you think such an algorithm exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directed graph linear algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775947/directed-graph-linear-algorithm)